# CSS scale height to match width - possibly with a formfactor

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have implemented a GoogleMapsV3 map in a twitterBootstrap basic responsive design site.

But my question is quite simple: i have:

```
<div id="map"></map>
```

and

```css
#map{ width: 100%; height: 200px }
```

I'd like to be able to change the height to a form factor. Like in this "in my dreams CSS"

```css
#map { width: 100%; height: width * 1.72 }
```

I have tried leaving out height, setting to auto, and all sorts of persentages - but only to make the div collapse on me always.

I have no problem writing a js-solution, but hope for a simple cleancut CSS solution, possible CSS3

If not possible, what would be the optimal way to js me out of this?? (timers, events...or the like)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For this, you will need to utilise JavaScript, or rely on the somewhat supported `calc()` CSS expression.

```
window.addEventListener("resize", function(e) {
    var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
    mapElement.style.height = mapElement.offsetWidth * 1.72;
});
```

Or using CSS calc (see support here: http://caniuse.com/calc)

```
#map {
    width: 100%;
    height: calc(100vw * 1.72)
}
```

Comment: Calc is no-go - thanks for caniuse.com link. But js is perfect for this!!

Comment: `height: calc(width * 1.75)` is not valid anyway

Comment: It didn't work for me until I added some units:

`mapElement.style.height = Math.floor(mapElement.offsetWidth * 1.72) + 'px';`

Comment: height:calc (100vw * 1.75) is valid - vw for View Width

Comment: @cyrille Wouldn't `175vw` be enough?!

Comment: @AlexisWilke Yes, you're right. `height: 175vw` is sufficient.

Comment: I wish `calc(height * 2)` or `calc(width * 2)` were valid

Answer (score 126):

**Most browsers now support *aspect-ratio* to help with this exact scenario: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/aspect-ratio**

**Without using aspect-ratio you can use the solution below.**

Here it is. Pure CSS. You do need one extra 'container' element.

**The fiddle**

<strike>(tinkerbin, actually): http://tinkerbin.com/rQ71nWDT</strike>
(Tinkerbin is dead.)

**The solution.**

***Note*** *I'm using an 100% throughout the example. You can use whichever percentage you'd like.*

Since height percentages are relative to the height of the parent element, we can't rely on it. We must rely on something else. Luckily padding is relative to the width - whether it's horizontal or vertical padding. In `padding-xyz: 100%`, 100% equals 100% of the box's width.

Unfortunately, padding is just that, padding. The content-box's height is 0. No problem!

Stick an absolutely positioned element, give it 100% width, 100% height and use it as your actual content box. The 100% height works because percentage heights on absolutely positioned elements are relative to the padding-box of the box their relatively positioned to.

HTML:

```
<div id="map_container">
  <div id="map">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
#map_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  padding-bottom: 100%;
}

#map {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: exactly what I wanted. But due to other factors i think, it does not work in my environment (either in twitterbootstrap, or due to the fact, that the contents is injected vis json)......and since greg had a simple js...i'll go with that

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo, The link you gave is broken now. :(

Comment: To change this example to other proportion (say 2:1) you have to change only `padding-bottom` (to 50% in this case) and not other instances of `100%`

Comment: Trick didn't work at all for me. Has this changed in later versions of Chrome?

Comment: Nope, it hasn't. You're probably missing something small. Check it out here http://jsbin.com/moficipako/edit?html,css,output

Comment: This answer is not correct!  The padding is calculated based on the containing box, i.e. the parent box (see: [W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#padding-properties)). So it will only work in cases where the width of the `#map_container` is `100%`. If you set the width of the `#map_container` to a fixed width of e.g. `250px` you will see that the height will still be equal to the width of the parent element.

Comment: Worked for me when I set padding-bottom to the ratio (height/width) as a percent.

Comment: Works like a charm, should be accepted answer, as calc() in this answer is invalid.

Comment: Appreciate the cogent explanation of the (suprising!) underlying CSS rules.

Comment: top-notch answer! "Luckily padding is relative to the width - whether it's horizontal or vertical padding": TIL

Answer (score 60):

You could try using `vw` for height.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length

Something like

```css
div#map {
     width: 100%;
     height: 60vw;
}
```

This would set the width of the div to 60% of the viewport width. You will probably need to use calc to adjust to take padding into account …

Comment: Can you explain a little more? Why doesn't this give the div a height of 60% view width and a width of 100% of the parent?

Comment: Here is the support table for viewport units. http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: @LukeP `height: 60%` tries* to set height to 60% of _parent element height_, while `height: 60vw` sets the height to 60% of _viewport width_, so they are quite different. (*Only works if the parent has a set height, as opposed to letting it be however high it needs in order contain it's children, which is usually what you want to do)

Answer (score 24):

```
.video {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* ratio 16/9 */
}

.video iframe {
    border: none;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**16:9**

padding-bottom = 9/16 * 100 = 56.25

Comment: sadly, this does not work.  It just adds space to the bottom of the div.

Answer (score 8):

Try viewports

You can use the width data and calculate the height accordingly

This example is for an 150x200px image

```
width: calc(100vw / 2 - 30px);
height: calc((100vw/2 - 30px) * 1.34);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use CSS like this to crop the image to a certain ratio and then using [object-fit](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_object-fit.asp) to center the image as you want.

CSS:

```
.ratio-crop {
   aspect-ratio: 1.72 / 1; //using the example size in the question
   object-fit: cover;
}
```

HTML:

```
<img src="/images.jpg" class="ratio-crop">
```

Answer (score 5):

I need to do "fluid" rectangles not squares.... so THANKS to JOPL .... didn't take but a minute....

```css
#map_container {
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     padding-bottom: 75%;
}


#map {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can set its `before` and `after` to force a constant width-to-height ratio

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="squared"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.squared {
  background: #333;
  width: 300px; 
}
.squared::before {
  content: '';
  padding-top: 100%;
  float: left;
}
.squared::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution with Jquery

```
$(window).resize(function () {
    var width = $("#map").width();
    $("#map").height(width * 1.72);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made similar thing with YouTube's IFRAME where the iframe is inside a grid that always changed based on portrait/landscape so this code worked for:

So the code for this question is:

```
// Layout resize
let height = window.innerHeight;
let width = window.document.getElementById('player').parentNode.clientWidth;
    height = width / 1.77;
```

```
<div id="player"></div>

... etc ..

function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
          // Layout resize
          let height = window.innerHeight;
          let width = window.document.getElementById('player').parentNode.clientWidth;
              height = width / 1.77;

          player = new YT.Player('player', {
            width: '100%',
            height: height,            
            videoId: currentVideoId,
            playerVars: {
              'autoplay': 0,
              'loop': 0,
              'mute': 0,
              'controls': 0,
              'enablejsapi': 1,
              'playsinline': 0,
              'rel': 0,
              'widget_referrer': 'http://my domain ...'
            },
            events: {
              'onReady': onPlayerReady,
              'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange,
              'onError': onError
            }
          });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, there is no reason to use calc or padding hacks when **aspect-ratio** is universally supported: https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_aspect-ratio

css:

```
width: 100%;
aspect-ratio: 1/1.72
```

or perhaps more readable:

```
aspect-ratio: 9/16
```

```html
<div style="display:block;width:100px;aspect-ratio:9/16;background:red"></div>
<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me describe the JS solution as a separate answer:

```
function handleResize()
{
  var mapElement = document.getElementById("map");
  mapElement.style.height = (mapElement.offsetWidth * 1.72) + "px";
}

<div id="map" onresize="handleResize()">...</div>
```

(or register the event listener dynamically).

`mapElement.style.width * 1.72` will not work, since it requires that the width be set explicitly on the element, either using the `width` DOM attribute or in the inline style's `width` CSS property.

Answer (score -2):

```
#map { 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100vw * 1.72 
}
```