# Styling Bootstrap's btn-group-justified, adding margins and sizing vertically

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'd like to style the original Bootstrap's `btn-group-justified` with radio `input` fields (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-examples).

The original style looks like this:
[image]

but I'd like to make every button a square-shaped button and give them all some whitespace between each other. Something like this:
[image]

I was trying with a bit modified html markup from Bootstrap examples

```css
[data-toggle="buttons"] .btn>input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.category-select .btn-container {
  position: relative;
  width: 19%;
  padding-bottom: 19%;
  float: left;
  height: 0;
  margin: 1%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn-container .btn,
.btn-container .btn input {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="btn-group-justified category-select" data-toggle="buttons">
  <div class="btn-container">
    <label class="btn category category-one">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> One
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <label class="btn category category-two">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Two
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <label class="btn category category-three">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Three
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <label class="btn category category-four">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option4"> Four
        </label>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <label class="btn category category-five">
          <input type="radio" name="options" id="option5"> Five
        </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

but of course this CSS doesn't style my buttons as I want to...
The functionality I'd like to achieve is to have 5 buttons, horizontally justified, responsive (square-shaped in all browser sizes) and to act like a radio-buttons group.

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work 'as intended'? Did the styles you apply not look good or did they not overwrite the bootstrap styles correctly? Do you just need the correct CSS that will overwrite the bootstrap styles and get it looking like your picture?

Comment: My styles did overwrite Bootstrap's defaults, but they don't look good :) I need corrected CSS which will make radio buttons look square and with margins... Will try Bass Jobsen's solution now...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**html**

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="btn-group blocks" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.blocks .btn-primary 
{
    padding: 24px 12px;
    margin: 0 5px;  
    border-radius: 0;
}
```

will looks like:

[image]

> If I apply btn-group-justified class instead of just btn-group, they
>   became justified but still not square-shaped, nor they have margin
>   between them

I don't think the `btn-group-justified` class will be intent to use without the `btn-group`. Although it don't seems to make a difference when you don't use `btn-group`.

`btn-group-justified` set the display to table. To add a margin between two cell you will need `border-spacing` in stead of `margin` (see: [Why is a div with "display: table-cell;" not affected by margin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16398823/why-does-a-div-with-display-table-cell-not-affected-by-margin))

now you have **html**:

```
<div class="container"> 
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified blocks" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
  </label>
</div>
```

**css**:

```
.blocks .btn-primary 
{
    padding: 24px 12px;
    border-radius: 0;

}
.blocks {border-spacing:5px;}
```

Which will look like:

[image]

Note you have rectangles instead of squares. `btn-group-justified` set the total with of the group to 100% of it's parent. To make squares you will need jQuery to set the height based on the (inner)width of your buttons. (see: [CSS scale height to match width - possibly with a formfactor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243075/css-scale-height-to-match-width-possibly-with-a-formfactor))

```
$(".btn-group-justified.blocks .btn").height($(".btn-group-justified.blocks .btn").innerWidth());
$(window).resize(function(){ $(".btn-group-justified.blocks .btn").height($(".btn-group-justified.blocks .btn").innerWidth()); });
```

Comment: Hm, but this wont't make justified button group, nor it makes my buttons square-shaped, especially when a button has a bit more text in it...

Comment: If I apply `btn-group-justified` class instead of just `btn-group`, they became justified but still not square-shaped, nor they have margin between them.

Comment: OK, thanks for helping! I thought I'll be able to solve this with CSS only but this is also a good solution. However, I think I'll try few different CSS-only options to achieve what I need... Will accept your answer though =)

Comment: If you want to cancel the space around your button group, you can add CSS with a negative margin equal to the space border : `border-spacing: 16px; margin: -16px;`