# vertically center image within responsive square div

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I am trying to center an image inside a div that scales responsively **and that is always square**.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3xma7/)

I've got the *always-square* part working thanks to the awesome [CSS-only option here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243075/css-scale-height-to-match-width-possibly-with-a-formfactor).

CSS:

```
.thumbnail_container {
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
    padding-bottom: 25%;
    float:left;
}

.thumbnail {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail_container vcenter-ext">
  <div class="thumbnail vcenter-int">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
  </div>
</div>
```

And the v-align in a div is usually pretty straight-forward with:

```
.vcenter-ext { display: table;}
.center-int { display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;}
```

But in the end, I can't seem to use them together... Can anyone point out my problems?!?

Comment: if you dont care about [=<IE9](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) then u could use flexbox: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: You could take a look at this answer , responsive squares with content : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20457076/1811992 it describes a good technique to center content inside responsive squares.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To solve your problem, you have to remove `display: table;` and `display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;` and have to add this :

```
.thumbnail img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

to center vertically your images. [This article](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/vertical-centering/) explains the method I used (Absolute Positioning and Stretching).

**Note :** my code is working because `.thumbnail`, the parent of `img` tags, has a `position: absolute` property.

You can have a look to [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3xma7/1/) to see the result.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x300" />
```

Css:

```
body{margin:0px auto;padding:0;text-align:center;}
div{padding:80px;width:25%;margin:0px auto;background:green;}
img{width:80%;margin:0px auto;padding:0;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8Fjsd/

Also:

vcenter-int doesnt exist